# How do I check for null on a .textContent call, when the element will only be there some of the time

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code, where I'm trying to check if an element I get by ID is not equal to null, but the actual checking to see if it's null or not still throws up a console error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null"... How can I stop this error from appearing?

It's important to add, that this element will not always be on the page and when it's not on the page, I don't want the console to output that error

```js
 var ldt = document.getElementById("ldt").textContent;
    if(ldt !== null) {
    document.getElementById("ldt").textContent = n + " " + t;
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do

```
var ldt = document.getElementById("ldt"); // no `.textContent` here
if (ldt !== null) {
    ldt.textContent = n + " " + t;
}
```